# Multithreading in Java ( Bank queue)

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to develep simulates a bank branch.I want to generate a new customer and add the customer to the queue(or ArrayList). If there are available tellers (there are 2 tellers), remove customer from the list and assign them to tellers. I used 2 threads, first one is generate customer and add to the list. Second one is belongs to tellers. I have some problem.

Customer class

```
public class Customer {
private int customerID;
private int processTime;

ArrayList<Integer> customerIDList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> processTimeList = new ArrayList<>();

public int getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}

public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
    this.customerID = customerID;
}

public int getProcessTime() {
    return processTime;
}

public void setProcessTime(int processTime) {
    this.processTime = processTime;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getCustomerIDList() {
    return customerIDList;
}

public void setCustomerIDList(ArrayList<Integer> customerIDList) {
    this.customerIDList = customerIDList;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getProcessTimeList() {
    return processTimeList;
}

public void setProcessTimeList(ArrayList<Integer> processTimeList) {
    this.processTimeList = processTimeList;
} 
}
```

Teller class

```
public class Teller {

private boolean status = true;

public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}
}
```

CustomerThread class

```
public class CustomerThread extends Thread {
Customer c = new Customer();
Methods method = new Methods();

@Override
public void run() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            c.getCustomerIDList().add(i+1);
            c.getProcessTimeList().add(method.generateProcessTime());

            System.out.println("ID  : " + c.getCustomerIDList().get(i) + " - Process Time : " + c.getProcessTimeList().get(i));
            Thread.sleep(100);   
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }  
} 
}
```

Between to customers 100 msec

TellerThread class

```
public class TellerThread extends Thread{
Customer c1 = new Customer();
Teller teller1 = new Teller();
Teller teller2 = new Teller();
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        while(c1.getProcessTimeList().isEmpty()) {
            if(teller1.isStatus()) {
                teller1.setStatus(false);

                System.out.println("Customer " + c1.getCustomerIDList().get(0) + " came teller1.");
                c1.getCustomerIDList().remove(0);
                Thread.sleep(c1.getProcessTimeList().get(0));
                System.out.println("Teller 1 is waiting of " + c1.getProcessTimeList().get(0) + " msec.");
                c1.getProcessTimeList().remove(0);
                teller1.setStatus(true);
                System.out.println("Teller 1 is Available.");
            }
            else if(teller2.isStatus()) {
                teller2.setStatus(false);

                System.out.println("Customer " + c1.getCustomerIDList().get(0) + " came teller2.");
                c1.getCustomerIDList().remove(0);
                Thread.sleep(c1.getProcessTimeList().get(0));
                System.out.println("Teller 2 is waiting of " + c1.getProcessTimeList().get(0) + " msec.");
                c1.getProcessTimeList().remove(0);
                teller2.setStatus(true);
                System.out.println("Teller 2 is Available");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("There is no customer..");
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TellerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }      
} 
}
```

and Test class

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {


        CustomerThread ct = new CustomerThread();
        TellerThread tt = new TellerThread();

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        es.execute(ct);
        es.execute(tt);

        es.shutdown();
}
}
```

When I execute this codes, I see only customers on the output. There are no tellers process. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your TellerThread is creating a new Customer all to itself, which of course has an empty list of incoming clients. Your code also has several issues with the model you are trying to build; you might want to read up on the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) and Java classes that make implementing this easier for you, like the classes that implement [java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Comment: Side note on code quality: always keep in mind that the names you are giving to your classes should tell a reader what is going on. In that sense, the field "status" in Teller is pretty ... useless. If you really want to use a boolean; than find another name; or if you want to keep the "status" wording; than consider using a different type (for example some kind of enum that has human readable values). Then: it is not good style that your customer has getters for the two lists - it should not be of interest to the outside. Instead: provide "add id" method on your customer class.